# Variable not incrementing in void update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the code given below,the variable `loop` **is not incremented**.It gives the output as 0 always.If we print loop after incrementing the value,the loop increments once.

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    int loop = 0;
    float[,] comp = new float[10,2];
    public Vector3 speed;

    void Start ()
    {
        speed = new Vector3(0,0.15f,0);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        comp = spawner.score;
        transform.Translate(speed);

        if(transform.position.y < -2)
        {   
            loop++;
            Debug.Log("Loop:"+loop);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you making a new class `move` every time before you call `move:Update()` by any chance? You could try making `loop` static or reusing your `move` class?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.I tried making loop static.But things remains same.

Comment: Post the code that creates an instance of `move` and call's `Update()`

Comment: are you sure this is the code you use? because i can tell for sure `Destrou` is no function of MonoBehaviour. But aside of that, ofc the value only get incremented once if you destroy the gameobject holding the script right after you print it out.

Comment: Thankyou for your concern.I meant Destroy().Sorry for that..'Post the code that creates an instance of move and call's Update()'Can you explain the.I am a begginer in programing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your gameobject with the move component is well under '-2' in the world pos ?
   (see -> `if(transform.position.y < -2)`) or the loop can be increment.
2. As "yes" say in his comment, what is `Destrou` ? 
   You want to use `Destroy` ? In this case why use loop, to count the all the destroy element ?
   So loop was increased and the object destroyed just after.
3. If `loop` is to count the number of element you must place the loop variable in an other script who cant be destroyed (for example : you can use [`Singleton`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) to access to it properly)

Comment: It was a typing mistake.I meant Destroy().Sorry for that.Actually i want to increment loop to 9 and then make loop=0 and increment to 9 and  repeat.

Comment: `loop++;     if (loop > 9)  loop = 0;`        

and like I said in the point 3 you need to put that in an other script